# Port Forwarding to Windows Desktop from Ubuntu Laptop?

Tags: networking, windows-10, port-forwarding, nat

I currently have a weird setup. I forgot to get a wireless card for my Windows 10 desktop so I am currently sharing my Ubuntu laptop's wireless internet with my Windows desktop via ethernet cable.

I am trying to get my Desktop to have an open NAT type for a game. I'
ve forwarded the correct ports to my Ubuntu laptop through my router but I don't really know how to forward them through my laptop to my desktop.

Could anyone suggest some reading I could do in order to figure out how to do this or help with any pointers? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

So, the issue is you need to forward ports between your Ubuntu laptop and Windows computer? If so, you could try using SSH. Install openssh-server on your laptop and an SSH client on your Windows. Then use the SSH client to connect to your laptop and handle the port forwarding.

Disclaimer: I have no idea if this is the most efficient way of doing it. I am just making a suggestion since no one else has answered yet.

Comment: If you *"have no idea"* why are you answering?